# Bypassing Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, annotations, servlet-filters

I recently wrote a basic implementation of annotations which bypasses servlets. I try and stay away from frameworks like spring and faces etc due to  their limitations and overheads.

The annotations which I have implemented basically bypasses servlets and just uses plain java objects which are delegated to by a filter to process the requests and responses and returns either some plain text, json or the request is forwarded by a request dispatcher. To achieve this I had to bypass the filter chain. I am currently planning on only using one filter.

Does anyone know what/if there are any risks involved in doing this? I know that web and app servers currently pool their servlets, but is there anything else which could pose a problem?

Comment: Some code sample would make your description more clear. I cannot imagine what you do and how.

Comment: When you say  _limitations and overheads_ what specifics you are referring to ?

Comment: I managed to get this up and running ages ago. I still use a filter which intercepts the servlet request paths and then don't forward the filter chain if the path matches one of my customized paths. The request is then dispatched to another static resource via request dispatcher. This filter needs to be the last filter in the chain however, the web / app server will automatically forward requests to a static resource and not doing so at this point is perfectly safe.